# How to fix: This factory function only works once

Tags: python, vpython

This function only works once and then not again can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from vpython import *
def create_cube(pos,size,front,back,left,right,bottom,top):
    c = [ pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0.5,0,0),size=size,color=left),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0.5,0,0),size=size,color=right).rotate(angle=radians(180),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0,0,0.5),size=size,color=front).rotate(angle=radians(90),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0,0,0.5),size=size,color=back).rotate(angle=radians(270),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0,0.5,0),size=size,color=bottom).rotate(angle=radians(90),axis=vector(0,0,1)),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0,0.5,0),size=size,color=top).rotate(angle=radians(270),axis=vector(0,0,1)),
    box(pos=pos,size = vector(0.9,0.9,0.9),color=color.black)]
    return compound(c)

topleftfrontcorner = create_cube(vector(-1,1,1),vector(0.5,0.90,0.90),color.red,color.black,color.blue,color.black,color.black,color.yellow)
topmiddlefrontside = create_cube(vector(0,0,0),vector(0.5,0.90,0.90),color.red,color.black,color.black,color.black,color.black,color.yellow)
```

I expect this function to output a custom 'cube' every time I call it not just once.

Comment: What do you mean by "works only once"? What's the exact behaviour? Are there any error messages or warnings?

Comment: The intended behavior is that it creates a custom cube wherever i pos is but after the first call it doesn't output another cube on the second call.

Comment: When I tried to post the following answer, it was deleted because it "didn't address the problem". So I'll say again:

The pyramid constructors are flawed. They have the form pyramid(...).rotate(...) followed by ",axis=vector(0,1,0)," which makes these axis calculations be elements to compound, and you get an error because "axis=vector(0,1,0" isn't a 3D object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `c`, and use `compound` on both `topleftfrontcorner` and `topmiddlefrontside`:

```
from vpython import *
def create_cube(pos,size,front,back,left,right,bottom,top):
    c = [ pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0.5,0,0),size=size,color=left),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0.5,0,0),size=size,color=right).rotate(angle=radians(180),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0,0,0.5),size=size,color=front).rotate(angle=radians(90),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0,0,0.5),size=size,color=back).rotate(angle=radians(270),axis=vector(0,1,0)),
    pyramid(pos=pos-vector(0,0.5,0),size=size,color=bottom).rotate(angle=radians(90),axis=vector(0,0,1)),
    pyramid(pos=pos+vector(0,0.5,0),size=size,color=top).rotate(angle=radians(270),axis=vector(0,0,1)),
    box(pos=pos,size = vector(0.9,0.9,0.9),color=color.black)]
    return c

topleftfrontcorner = create_cube(vector(-1,1,1),vector(0.5,0.90,0.90),color.red,color.black,color.blue,color.black,color.black,color.yellow)
topmiddlefrontside = create_cube(vector(0,0,0),vector(0.5,0.90,0.90),color.red,color.black,color.black,color.black,color.black,color.yellow)
compound(topleftfrontcorner, topmiddlefrontside)
```

Doing so gives me:
[image]

Maybe someone more familiar with `vpython` can explain more, but in general there's a difference between creating a cube and rendering a cube. The reason why you don't see two cubes in your snippet is that the program is still rendering the first cube (a blocking operation), and hasn't even evaluated the second function call. You can see that's the case by putting a `print("hello!")` between the two function calls; `"hello!"` never gets printed because the program is still busy rendering `topleftfrontcorner`.

In the updated code snippet, we construct two cubes, then render them at the same time.